# Array of objects to line chart series? (+ for Crossfilter solution)

Tags: javascript, time-series, crossfilter

In JavaScript, how do I transform a "long table format" to a data structure suitable for a line chart:

```
var data = [
  {"type":"A"," year":2000," value":50},
  {"type":"A"," year":2001," value":51},
  {"type":"A"," year":2002," value":52},
  {"type":"B"," year":2000," value":60},
  {"type":"B"," year":2001," value":55},
  {"type":"B"," year":2002," value":57}
]

=>

var series = [ 
  {type: "A", values : [{x: 2000, y: 50}, {x: 2001, y: 52},] },
  {type: "B", values : [{x: 2000, y: 60}, {x: 2001, y: 55},] },
]
```

A vanilla JavaScript solution as well as a solution with the Crossfilter library - that can work on any dimension of the data - would be valuable:
https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, but not staightforward ; )

Have a look at https://github.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/pull/91

you'll have something like :

```
cr = crossfilter(data);
typeDim=cr.dimension(function(d) {return d.type});
typeGroup=typeDim.group();

yearDim=cr.dimension(function(d) {return d.year});
valDim=cr.dimension(function(d) {return d.value});

yearTypeGroup = dateDimension.group();
yearTypeGroup.reduce( 
    // add
    // pivot[0].idx()[i] returns the index of statusGroup
    // the reduce function hence construct a key-value object, keys being indexes of the pivot group. 
    function(p, v, i, pivot) { 
         ++p[pivot[0].idx()[i]].count;
        p[pivot[0].idx()[i]].value += +v.value;
        return p;
    },
    //remove
    function(p, v,i,pivot) {
        --p[pivot[0].idx()[i]].count;
        p[pivot[0].idx()[i]].value -= +v.value;
        return p;
    },
    //init
    function(pivot) {
        var l, i, obj ={};
        if(l = pivot[0].all().length){
            for(i=0; i<l; ++i) {
                obj[i] = {count:0, value:0}
            }
        }
        return obj
    }
);

yearTypeGroup.pivot(typeGroup)
```

Good luck ; ) 
C.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! The d3.nest method is also pretty neat but I am glad to learn how to do the same with crossfilter.

Comment: You are right, d3.nest can be usefull for this as well, but you'll have to re-nest after each crossfilter filtering. With the method above, your chart series are going to reflect crossfilter grouping and filtering on the fly.